# cakephp - difficulty to access a specific information in my controller

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

I have these tables and the relationships between them:

- 1 project hasmany configurationcontext 1 issuetype hasmany
- optionconfiguration hasmany configurationcontext hasmany
- optionconfiguration (does not exist intermediate table)

My goal is to get information like this query.

```
SELECT IT.id, IT.pname
FROM configurationcontext               CC
LEFT OUTER JOIN optionconfiguration     OC ON OC.fieldconfig = CC.fieldconfigscheme
LEFT OUTER JOIN issuetype               IT ON IT.id = OC.optionid
WHERE CC.project = 10000
```

my doubts:
- which the controller to use to create a function that return me this information?
- How do I get this information?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I have your model names correct, this should do the trick:

```
$this->ConfigurationContext->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'optionconfiguration',
            'alias' => 'OptionConfiguration',
            'type' => 'LEFT OUTER JOIN',
            'conditions' => array(
                'OptionConfiguration.fieldconfig = ConfigurationContext.fieldconfigscheme'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'issuetype',
            'alias' => 'IssueType',
            'type' => 'LEFT OUTER JOIN',
            'conditions' => array(
                'IssueType.id = OptionConfiguration.optionid'
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'ConfigurationContext.project' => 10000
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'IssueType.id',
        'IssueType.pname'
    )
));
```

I haven't tried type "LEFT OUTER JOIN" but I don't see why it wouldn't work, maybe look into using containable to avoid using joins if you can.

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` are equal, in CakePHP just specify `LEFT` as type